# AJAX success not executing

Tags: ajax, django

I have a form that submits using ajax. The submit is always successful, but nothing in my success statement ever executes. I have my django view return a `status = 200`, but still nothing. Can anyone tell why this isn't executing? In my terminal, it shows that I have a broken pipe error, but I've read that I can ignore those on my dev server. Not sure if that has anything to do with it.

My Form:

```
<form onsubmit="createAdd({{ newID }}, {{ user.get_profile.id }})" class="form-horizontal create" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="newName">Name*</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="newName" id="name" required>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create"><i class="icon-wrench icon-white"> </i> Create </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

My AJAX function:

```
function createAdd(event, user){  // Creates a custom event and automatically gives creator ownership
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var loc = document.getElementById('loc').value;
    var start = document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('datepicker2').value;
    var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
    var jqxhr = $.ajax( "/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/", {
        type: "POST", 
        data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user}
    })
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("hello") })
}
```

I don't actually want to go to Google, I'm just trying to get it to redirect *somewhere*. It also won't execute if I put an `alert` in there either.

My full view:

```
@login_required
def createCustom(request):

    newID = len(customEvent.objects.all())
    newName = request.POST['name']
    newLoc = request.POST['loc']
    newStart = request.POST['start']
    newEnd = request.POST['end']
    newTags = request.POST['tags']
    newURL = "/eventc/" + str(newID)

    e = customEvent(event_id = newID, title = newName, start = newStart, end = newEnd, location = newLoc, tags = newTags, url = newURL)
    e.save()

    event_id = request.POST['event_id']
    user = request.POST['profile']
    event = customEvent.objects.get(event_id = event_id)
    user = Profile.objects.get(id = user)
    user.ownedEvent.add(event)

    return HttpResponse('', content_type="application/json")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: any 500s in the browser console ?

Comment: Nope none in console or terminal

Comment: Can you see the 200 response using something like Firebug or dev tools?

Comment: I see it in my terminal
`[10/Jul/2013 11:31:54] "POST /eventsearch/eventsearch/create/ HTTP/1.1" 200 16414`

Comment: What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: The one provided by Google. Shows 1.10.1

Answer (score 3):

You need return in anwer - JSON
For example

```
def answer(request):    
    # same you code
    payload = {'success': True}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(payload), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 2):

In [the `jQuery.ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) I can read this:

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

So, I would follow the example there and try if this works instead:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
// perform other work here ...
// Set another completion function for the request above
jqxhr.always(function() { alert("second complete"); });
```

Adapted to your code, it may look like this:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "/eventsearch/eventsearch/createCustom/", {
     data: {name: name, loc: loc, start: start, end: end, tags: tags, event_id: event, profile: user}
    })
    .done(function() { alert("success"); })
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
    .always(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

I'm not completely sure about data, I was just following the docs.

Also, it should be good to add `mimetype` to the response like this:

```
return HttpResponse('', mimetype="application/json")
```

I think I've read somewhere that Ajax won't work if this is not set with Django, I don't remember where, I'm trying to find it on Google, give it a try.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely on the right track! The .fail function is the one that always executes though and my function no longer works. Not quite sure why because the terminal is showing a 200.

Comment: You should combine this with nmware's answer, I think you need to set `content_type='application/json'` to `HttpResponse` to make it work.

Comment: @Xonal I edited the answer with an example of the response that may work.

Comment: Tried both mimetype and content_type. Neither made it work again.

Comment: There must be a silly error we're missing here. Try post the full view's method and the full response you're receiving in the browser.

Comment: I've been messing around with it some more and the function works again. I get the error response, but the function itself is doing what it's supposed to and creating the event. When I change the alert to `window.location.href = "google.com"` though, that doesn't execute. I'll post my current full code right now

Comment: And that code never yield any exception? Can you post the full response you're getting in your browser? i.e dump the response from the console here.

Comment: Console is empty when I submit the form. I posted an error I occasionally (not every time) get in my terminal.

Comment: No, you can ignore that, I was referring to the browser. You can user Firebug if in Firefox, it would be great to see both, how the request is being sent by the browser and how it receive the response. You can see this in the network tab in Firebug or Chrome inspector

Comment: Just got Firebug. No errors are output, just a header with what seems to be standard info. No sign of exceptions.